# deleting pod items

Tags: wordpress, podscms

does any one have any suggestions on deleting pod items in wordpress using triggers such as a button click or something similiar?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'pod' items - is this a custom post type, something from a plugin..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you still having issues with this? $id isn't the same as the pod_id.

Try this:

```
<?php
$id = 3;
$Record = new Pod('product',$id);
$api = new PodAPI();
$api->drop_pod_item(array('pod_id'=>$Record->get_pod_id()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think he/she is talking about the [Pod CMS plugin](http://podscms.org/). There's a [drop_pod method](http://podscms.org/codex/drop_pod) in the [API](http://podscms.org/codex/), so you just need to call it when you click some button or something.

Comment: Ya. I am talking about the Pod CMS plugin.
@Javier- I tried using the drop_pod_item method but i get an error.
I am using the following code -
$id = 3;
$params = array( 'pod_id' => $id );
$api = new PodAPI( 'product' );
$api->drop_pod_item($params);

But i get the following error-

Error: SQL failed; SQL: SELECT pre_drop_helpers, post_drop_helpers FROM wp_pod_types WHERE id = ; Response: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: does empty($id)===true ?? seems to be that is your problem, the argument is empty.